# Method that returns adress of its struct in Go language

Tags: go, data-structures, linked-list

In my attempt to create a linked list data structure I've declared two structs.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type listElement struct {
    data int         
    next *listElement 
}

type List struct {
    first *listElement 
    last  *listElement 
    len   int          
}
```

I want to create a method that returns an empty list. So far I've only been able to create the function

```
func new() *List {
    return &List{}
}
```

This is the same result I've seen in multiple data structure repositories. Is it possible to create a method `List.new()` that returns a new empty list?

Comment: The convention in Go is to name constructor functions `New<TypeName>`, or sometimes simply `New`.

Comment: You can use [`new(List)`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#new) for simple allocations. For more complex ones you need to define your own "constructor" functions as already pointed out by Tim Cooper. It's not possible to call methods in your desired fashion, i.e. `T.M()`, you would have to pass an instance of `T` to `M` because `M` is really just a function with `T` as its first argument, e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/8o83IC_V717.

Comment: We can use reflection `Set` to set the value of struct to zero. Else just like @mkopriva said you can use a pointer receiver to empty the value of struct. Like https://play.golang.org/p/Np9UsthKlOZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course you can define a method that returns a List value, but since you need a List value to call a method this is kind of awkward:

```
package main

type List struct{}

func (List) New1() *List {
    return &List{}
}

func (*List) New2() *List {
    return &List{}
}

func main() {
    _ = List{}.New1()
    _ = (&List{}).New2()
    _ = (*List)(nil).New2()
}
```

I honestly don't see how this is better than a NewList function, which is idiomatic in Go:

```
func NewList() *List {
    return &List{}
}
```

If your package is called list, name the function New instead, so it is called as `list.New()`.

The arguments and bodies would be the same in all cases. They only differ in how they are called, and the package function is easiest to use. (See the link in JimB's comment for one more variant that is slightly different.)

It seems you have not yet read [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names), which suggests most of the above.

> The function to make new instances of ring.Ring—which is the definition of a constructor in Go—would normally be called NewRing, but since Ring is the only type exported by the package, and since the package is called ring, it's called just New, which clients of the package see as ring.New.

Comment: @JimB, didn't know that works. The arguments are different in this one though, so I'll leave it out of the answer.

Comment: It’s called a [method expression](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_expressions)